# How does jenkins master discover slave instance

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I am trying to setup jenkins master-slave environment. After searching online, there are many instructions to show how to setup it from scratch. But my case is a bit different, there is a jenkins instance currently running in AWS EC2 environment. And I want to make this instance to be slave and setup another jenkins instance as a master to control that slave. I followed this link: 'https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines' but it doesn't mention how to discover slave instances from master. Is there a way for me to setup the master to discover existed slave instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be with hostname and ssh key

Comment: Welcome to SO. This should be a comment, not an answer.